# Is it okay to ask and discuss about questions which come in exams which come in German univerisities?

Tags: exams, germany

I am partaking in some exams provided by German universities. Would it be okay if I were to discuss the questions after the exam online, e.g., by posting on the appropriate Stack Exchange? There were no rules written against it, but I heard datenschutz (data privacy law) is quite strict in Germany, hence my question.

Comment: This (Academia) would not be the forum for it in any case. And, the rules, if any, wouldn't be SE rules, but university rules. Ask them how widely you can discuss "old" questions.

Comment: I am aware of all that, I am asking this to people who study there, what their experience with this was

Comment: "There were no rules written against it" - this depends, if you intend to repost exams online, this could violate copyright (see e.g. https://www.bmbf.de/bmbf/shareddocs/kurzmeldungen/de/was-forschende-und-lehrende-wissen-sollten.html#:~:text=Ja.,in%20der%20Regel%20urheberrechtlich%20geschützt.)

Comment: Germany is a big place, and different universities might also have different policies. But you would probably need to ask whoever wrote the exam in question for permission, as with other course materials.

Comment: Note also that this has nothing to do with Datenschutz. Datenschutz best translates as data privacy and is about handling personal information about people. It doesn't say anything about university exam questions.

Comment: Adding to @coffee_into_plots answer, Germany is not only big, but education is organized on a federal level, not on country level. So there are more differences than you might think from one federal state to the other.

Comment: When I was a student in Germany, the student organization in each department had a room full of folders in which students had deposited notes about memorializing exam questions after the exam was over. At the time (1993-1998), the system required a good number of oral exams, so there were no written exam questions to rely on, but people were diligent writing out what they had been asked, and it was fantastic to prep for your own exams. It was universally done, and I see no reason why this system can not also work if these questions are put on websites.

Comment: While it is correct that ultimately the university (or department or course) rules count, I think this is a legitimate and answerable question for academia.sx: it is about German academic culture. Voted to reopen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are three reasons why it may not be okay:

- **Copyright:** If you are copying the text of the question instead of just describing it, this would be a copyright violation. Same goes for posting photographs, screenshots of the question or sketches therein.
- **Special Rules:** It could be that you agree not to share the contents of the exam by any means by enrolling or writing the exam. This should be easy to find out by checking all rules you agreed to. FWIW, we had such a rule for online exams during the pandemic, but only for three hours after the exam (this was to account for students receiving time extensions).
- Even if not against any law or rule, **the author may be angry anyway**. My experience with the German academic system is that teachers expect all exams to be public knowledge amongst the students at their university as soon as they are written. I do not expect my students to request permission (even as a courtesy) to discuss an exam I posed, as long as they respect copyright and the exam is truly over. However, there are almost certainly some excentric professors out there who consider discussing their questions inappropriate, even if it breaks no law or rules.

> but I heard datenschutz is quite strict in Germany, hence my question.

*Datenschutz* is the protection of personal data. It has no bearing on the tasks of an exam, as they are not personal data.

Comment: You probably mean 'eccentric', not 'excentric'.

Comment: *"It could be that you agree not to share the contents of the exam by any means by enrolling or writing the exam."* It would be interesting whether such a rule (beyond the very harmless three hours example you mentioned) would have any chance to stand in court. This seems to intervene with the students' constitutional right to freely choose their profession. I wouldn't bet a dime on the university winning such a case. Another question is how such a rule could actually be enforced - what if a student simply breaks the rule after the exam?

Comment: @Anyon: AFAICT, *excentric* is just an excentric spelling of *eccentric.*

Comment: @JochenGlueck: *This seems to intervene with the students' constitutional right to freely choose their profession.* – I don’t think see how being “forced” to agree to a non-disclosure clause would qualify as a restriction of this freedom. Essentially any job that fundamentally is about working with humans (educator, nurse, therapist) will involve some sort of training with humans, which in turn will probably come with some non-disclosure agreement. Similar, you have to accept lab rules in many experimental fields.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft In the sense of "off-center", yes. The meaning of strange and unusual, when applied to a person, is only listed under 'eccentric' in the English dictionaries I've consulted. Of course, the etymology involves the prefix 'ex', and this is preserved in many other European languages.

Comment: @JochenGlueck: *Another question is how such a rule could actually be enforced - what if a student simply breaks the rule after the exam?* – You would probably somehow tie this to the examination rules. Examination rules in turn are public regulations and thus interfering with the regular operation of exams is as an administrative offence (Ordnungswidrigkeit) which can lead to a fine. On top, interfering with exams can usually be punished like cheating for students in the programme. (Mind, however, that I do consider such a rule bad, but not due to unconstitutionality or unenforceability.)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Hmm, I spent quite a while searching but couldn't find a court judgement for a case close to the one we're discussing. There seems to be a general concensus that article 12 of the German constitution affects exam regulations, but the details seem non-trivial (at least for me). I'm having difficulties to follow your examples, though: these are cases where the restrictions have their rationale in the subject being tested (and the first example also involves conflicting basic rights of other people). That's not the case for a rule not to discuss the exam questions with anyone.

Comment: Regarding "Ordnungswidrigkeiten": it seems to be more complictated than that: according to [§ 3 OWiG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/owig_1968/__3.html) "Ordnungswidrigkeiten" have to be defined by law. I checked for the federal state NRW: according to § 63(5) of the [Hochschulgesetz NRW](https://recht.nrw.de/lmi/owa/br_text_anzeigen?v_id=10000000000000000654), cheating (more precisely: "Täuschung über Prüfungsleistungen") counts as "Ordnungswidrigkeit", but other types of interfering with exams are not listed there.

Comment: Regardless of what the law says, it is generally a bad idea to anger a person who has power over you.

Comment: @JochenGlueck: *I'm having difficulties to follow your examples* – I guess, my main point regarding constitutionality is this: Universities can impose all sorts of rules regarding studies and exams as long as complying with them is not a burden, restricts who can study, etc. I don’t see how a non-disclosure clause does this. Also, I think you can probably argue against students not being allowed to discuss the exam at all, since it would preclude them from taking legal actions against bad questions, but revealing the questions online is a different thing.

Comment: @JochenGlueck: *cheating (more precisely: "Täuschung über Prüfungsleistungen") counts as "Ordnungswidrigkeit", but other types of interfering with exams are not listed there.* – Not exactly. Violating any rule that concerns cheating can lead to fine; so it’s not only cheating per se. A typical example would be an outsider who helps a student to cheat or who interrupts an exam, forcing a repetition. As the only reason to keep exams secret is as an anti-cheating measure (no matter how that actually works out), it would be captured by this.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: *"Not exactly. Violating any rule that concerns cheating can lead to fine; so it’s not only cheating per se.*" Fair enough. This leaves the question whether the discussion of exam questions after the exam can be considered relevant for cheating (in future exams). I tried again to search online for such a case that was treated in court, but I could not find anything.

Comment: I'd like to add to the reasons against, that OP may talk to the professor about this and chances are that they find them quite open to this. At least my experience as student was that professors even encouraged exam question collections. Oh, and I once had an interview weekend for a scholarship, where one interviewer specifically checked (with a weird question where the answer would be easily known for those who had been talking about the interview but not to anyone who didn't expect that question) whether we were talking about what questions they asked. (If anyone wonders: talking was good)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: I can see how restricting speech about a passed exam may be considered an undue burden to the student. And how restricting to find out what exactly to expect in an exam can also be considered an undue burden. Undue also in the sense that the German academic system has found exam procedures that are not hampered by knowledge of old exams. (And maybe also keeping in mind that for official exams such as the driver's license theory the pool of questions is publicly available and meant to be used for learning).

Comment: The health care scenarios IMHO are not good examples here, since privacy requirements there are nothing one signs like an NDA (which is a contract), they are legal requirements and thus at a thoroughly different level. I guess one has to sign that one is *aware* of them like one signs that one is *aware* of the anti-corruption laws - but they need to be kept anyways, signature or not.